# d3.js: Generating pie charts over map, unexpected NaN

Tags: d3.js

**The data**

I've got a `.csv` which has data of the following format:

> city, industry, X, Non-X, latitude, longitude, Total

**The goal**

I've made a map of the country, and have created some `g` elements over each capital (using the `latitude` and `longitude` data). Within each `g` element, I'd like to create a pie chart, showing the proportions of `X` and `Non-X`. I'd like the radius of each pie to be a function of `Total`.

**The code**

Skipping over creating the map, etc, here's my function to create the pie charts (scroll down; a bit long):

```
            function drawPies(csv) {

                var radius = d3.scale.sqrt()
                    .domain([1, d3.max(csv, function(d) { 
                        return d.Total; 
                    })])
                    .range([2, 25]);

                var color = d3.scale.ordinal();
                var arc = d3.svg.arc();
                var pie = d3.layout.pie();

                var circleLayer = d3.select("svg")
                                .append("g")
                                .attr("class", "circleLayer");

                var pies = circleLayer.selectAll("g")
                    .data(csv)
                    .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("id", function(d) { return d.city; })
                    .attr("class", "capitals")
                    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                    .on("mouseout", mouseout)
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0] + "," + projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1] + ")";
                        });

                arc.outerRadius(function (d) { return radius(d.Total); })
                    .innerRadius(0);

                pies.append("text")
                    .text("Hi");

                pies.append("path")
                    .attr("d", arc) //this is not working...
                    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d['X']); });
            }
```

`pies.append("text")` works fine; the text elements appear at the right lat and long. Something's wrong with my `arc` variable; and I think it must be to do with how I've defined `.outerRadius()`. The `path` elements are created, but I'm getting `NaN` (and, hence, no pies). Here's what the HTML looks like from an example `g` element for each pie chart:

`<path d="MNaN,NaNA4.859251238796309,4.859251238796309 0 1,1 NaN,NaNL0,0Z">`

I suspect it's something with how I'm binding the data, and how I'm passing the data into `arc.outerRadius()`. I've tried re-binding the data to each `pies` element; I've also tried binding `.data(d3.layout.pie())` (following Mike Bostock's example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305111)), but that just doesn't generate `d` altogether.

What I'd like to do, is have `d['X']` and `d['Non-X']` be used to generate each pie's `arc.outerRadius()` (I think) - any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using `d3.csv` to retrieve your csv file?  Do you convert the data into numeric data after you fetch it?

Comment: Also, you don't seem to use your `pie` function.  Further, you also don't specify a value accessor on your `d3.layout.pie()`.   What values are you expecting to create the pie from?  Just d['X'] and d['Non-X']? So each pie would have two slices?

Comment: @Mark - Yep, data's being pulled in via `d3.csv`. I'm destringing `d['X']` and `d['Non-X']`; they're showing up as floats when I console.log. D'oh - you're right, I'm not using pie. Though is that something I'd bind to each path (similar to [this example by Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305111))?

Comment: OK, yeah, I'm definitely confused about `pie` - specifically, I've got `var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) { return d['X']; })`, and I'm binding that to all the `g` elements via `var pies = circleLayer.selectAll("g").data(pie(csv))`... That's just throwing all sorts of NaNs. How do I have both d['X'] and d['Non-X'] entered in the `pie` value stuff?

Comment: So, each run of data represents a pie chart and each pie is built off two columns of that row?

Comment: Exactly. I've made a bit of progress. I'm using `.value(function(d) { return d; })` in my pie function. I'm assuming the pie function is just finding the floats in my array (==a row in my csv). I'd like to make a pie chart per row. Each slice of the pie will be those two different columns, X and Non-X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a nested selection:

```
  var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(20)
      pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function(d){ return d });

  var pies = svg.selectAll('.pie') //<-- this is each row
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'pie')

  ...

  pies.selectAll('.slice')
    .data(function(d){
      return pie([d.X, d.NonX]); //<-- this is each slice
    })
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'slice')
    .attr('d',  arc);
```

---

Working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var data = [{
        X: Math.random(),
        NonX: Math.random(),
        Total: Math.random() * 10
      },{
        X: Math.random(),
        NonX: Math.random(),
        Total: Math.random() * 10
      },{
        X: Math.random(),
        NonX: Math.random(),
        Total: Math.random() * 10
      },{
        X: Math.random(),
        NonX: Math.random(),
        Total: Math.random() * 10
      }];
      
      data.forEach(function(d){
        d.pieVals = [d.X, d.NonX];
      })
      
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 500)
        .attr('height', 500);
        
      var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(20)
          pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .value(function(d){ return d }),
          color = d3.scale.category10();
      
      var pies = svg.selectAll('.pie')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'pie')
        .attr('transform',function(d,i){
          return 'translate(' + 20 + ',' + (i + 1) * 40 + ')';
        })
        
      pies.selectAll('.slice')
        .data(function(d){
          return pie([d.X, d.NonX]);
        })
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d',  arc)
        .style('fill', function(d,i){
          return color(i);
        });
      
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works! Thanks for your patience, Mark - that's perfect. And helps clarify a lot about what data is bound to what.