# Putting pie charts on map

Tags: d3.js

**My Goal**

I want to create a map which combines a choropleth map and a symbol map. Therefore, I want to put several pie charts on top of the map.

**My problem**
I already created the choropleth map based on [this tutorial](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch12.html#_acquiring_and_parsing_geodata). Now I want to replace the sized points in the example with pie charts using a csv of the following format:

> Region, Group1, Group2, Group3, Group4, lat, lon

After looking at several threads, especially at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399956/d3-js-generating-pie-charts-over-map-unexpected-nan), my function looks something like this:

```
                d3.csv("Bevoelkerung-Altersstruktur-2010-lat.csv", function drawPies (data) {

                var radius = d3.scale.sqrt()
                .domain([1, d3.max(csv, function(d) { 
                    return d.Total; 
                })])
                .range([2, 25]);

               var color = d3.scale.ordinal();

               var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(20)
               pie = d3.layout.pie()
               .value(function(d){ return d });

                var pie = d3.layout.pie();

                var pies = svg.selectAll('.pie')
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'pie')
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0] + "," + projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1] + ")";
                    });

                pies.selectAll('.slice')
                .data(function(d){
                return pie([d.Group1, d.Group2, d.Group3, d.Group4]); })
                .enter()
                .append('path')
                .attr('d',  arc)
                .style('fill', function(d,i){
                return color(i);});

                });
```

Unfortunately this does nothing at all, I only get to see the choropleth map. Does anybody have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general your code looks ok but I'm wondering a couple things:

1.) Does you CSV file header really have spaces in it?  When `d3` parses it you'll end up with property names with spaces as well.

2.)  Have you coerced your data into numbers?  I don't see any conversion and it'll come out of the csv as strings:

```
d3.csv("Bevoelkerung-Altersstruktur-2010-lat.csv", 
  function(d) { 
    return {
      Group1: +d.Group1, 
      Group2: +d.Group2, 
      Group3: +d.Group3,  
      Group4: +d.Group4, 
      lat: +d.lat, 
      lon: +d.lon
    }; 
  }, function drawPies (data) {
  ...
});
```

Regardless, here's a [quick bl.ock.org example](http://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/15b5d10cfb822e9032bb2b6a86a9cb35), based off of [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) that add pie charts.

Comment: No, the CSV doesn't have spaces in it, I just put them in to give my example a better readability. But thank you for your input, it solved my problem.